# 20.04 "No network interfaces detected" when installing Focal as KVM guest

Tags: networking, server, system-installation, iso, kvm-virtualization

I obtain the Ubuntu Server 20.04 `iso` file from  http://www.cdimage.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-server/daily/20200302/

I've tried several ways to install under KVM, but always hit "No network interfaces detected".

I've never encountered this with earlier Ubuntu releases.

Googling `ubuntu "no network interfaces detected"` turns up nothing in the past year.

Are there additional steps I need to perform?

Comment: You don't make it quite clear whether you are installing 20.04 from scratch on a new VM, or on top of an earlier release on a VM that is already working.  My first-blush question is:  *"do you,* in fact, have any network interfaces defined in this VM?"  Just askin' ... **:-)** ... check on this "d'oh possibility" first.

Comment: It's a completely fresh install using Virtual Machine Manager defaults.

Comment: Bug reports and problems specific to development version of Ubuntu should be reported on Launchpad so that developers can see, track and fix these issues. Please see https://meta.askubuntu.com/a/872/197910

Answer (score 1):

It seems like a defective `daily`.

With this URL I had no problem:

http://www.cdimage.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-server/daily/current/

Comment: There is support for the development version of Ubuntu over on [Ubuntu Forums](https://ubuntuforums.org/forumdisplay.php?f=427). The development version is not supported here. I have been having intermittent issues with KVM on 20.04 also.